# How to identify if MKPointAnnotation has been pressed in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Using a `for loop` I have stored a unique URL in each annotation using a tag create in a class named CustomPointAnnotation. I am trying to print out the URL of the annotation that has been pressed. **The problem is my output console in Xcode prints nothing when I click on an annotation.**

I tried to follow this guide: [How to identify when an annotation is pressed which one it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51603667/11480234)

I replicated all the code but it is not detecting if the annotation was clicked.

> How do I know if the annotation is clicked?

**Here is the CustomPointAnnotation.**

```swift
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
        var tag: String!
    }
```

I declared the variable tag so I can store a unique variable for each annoation.

**My `ViewController` class:**

In the ViewController class there is **a loop which iterates through my Firebase Database JSON files:**

```swift
func displayCordinates() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let storageRef = ref.child("waterfountains")

    storageRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let annotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
            let dict = child.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            annotation.title = "Water Fountain"
            annotation.tag = dict["url"] as? String
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dict["lat"] as! Double, longitude: dict["long"] as! Double)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
    })
}
```

**The annotations are displayed by calling the functions in `viewDidLoad`:**

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    displayCordinates()
}
```

**A function which should detect if an annotation has been clicked:**

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation {
        print(annotation.tag!)
    }  
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: `mapView:didSelect` is a `MKMapViewDelegate` method. If you do not set `mapView.delegate = self` on your `ViewController` this function will never get triggered. Try setting a breakpoint in the function to confirm it's not getting triggered on tap, and look over your code to see if you set the delegate. Typically it would get set in `ViewDidLoad`, probably before performing any other operations with the `mapView`. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: self.mapView.delegate = self; try this in the view controller viewWillAppear method hope that helps.

Comment: @NSGangster thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapView:didSelect:` is a `MKMapViewDelegate` method. If you do not set `mapView.delegate = self` on your `ViewController` this function will never get triggered.

Typically it would get set in `ViewDidLoad`. before performing any other operations with the mapView. Changing your `ViewDidLoad` to look like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.delegate = self
    displayCordinates()
}
```

should fix your issue. For more information on the `protocol`/`delegate` design pattern all over the apple frameworks, I suggest [this swift article](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) from [the Swift Programming Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).

More specifically to your case, check out all the other functionality/control you can bring with your implementation of `MKMapView` on your `ViewController` by checkout out the apple docs on [`MKMapViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate). This will cover things like monitoring when the map finishes loading, when it fails, when the user's location is updated, and more things you may want to increase the functionality of your app and provide a great user experience.